# Windows update KB3013769, KB3013816 failing on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I have two optional updates to install on my laptop, a lenovo Thinkpad X201. All mandatory updates have already been applied. It has failed repeatedly, despite me doing several reboots.

[image]

If I click Install, I get this screen after a while:

[image]

I have tried the Windows Update Troubleshooter, and it looks like this:

[image]

I click Next and I eventually get:

[image]

[image]

If I reboot and try again, I go through the same loop, although the error message is slightly different:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I found [these instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-Update-error-80240016) when doing research on this problem.  Of course it seems there are some [other steps](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-update/error-code-80240016/730af6de-fd28-46e7-b017-17e6118d3fbb?auth=1) you should take also.  [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_install/error-code-how-80242006/9776c82c-0163-41cf-ad96-65d157d7628e) are some additional steps that might need to be done.

Comment: I just tried that, it failed to stop initially, but I waited a few minutes, and tried again. Successfully stopped and started the service, but the update fails.

Comment: You tried everything between all three links I provided in less then 4 minutes?

Comment: Only the first one, sorry multi-tasking and didn't go back to the others. Doing them now... :D

Comment: 0x80242006 = WU_E_UH_INVALIDMETADATA (A handler operation could not be completed because the update contains invalid metadata.). Download the updaets from Microsoft download center and install the MSU files on your own: http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/default.aspx

Comment: Sounds exactly like problem I am dealing with now. Are you able to manually start BITS?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to resolve the errors,

**Step 1 : Use System File Checker to repair damaged Windows files**:

Use the System File Checker tool to repair damaged Windows files. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open an elevated command prompt.
2. Run the "sfc /scannow" command.
3. Try to install update again.

You can read the following for more information about the System File Checker tool, [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833).

**Step 2: Run the DISM tool**

If the problem continues, use the `Deployment Image Servicing and Management` (DISM) tool to fix Windows Update corruption errors. To do this, follow these steps:
 - Open an elevated command prompt.
 - Run the "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth" command.
Important When you run this command, DISM uses Windows Update to provide the files that are required to fix corruptions. However, if your Windows Update client is already broken, use a running Windows installation as the repair source, or use a Windows side-by-side folder from a network share or from a removable media, such as the Windows DVD, as the source of the files. To do this, run the following command instead:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess
```

*Note:* Replace the `C:\RepairSource\Windows` placeholder with the location of your repair source. For more information about using the DISM tool to repair Windows, reference [Repair a Windows Image](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824869.aspx).

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/958044

Comment: sfc /scannow: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations. DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth: The restore operation completed successfully. The component store corruption was repaired.The operation completed successfully. Windows update failed again.